# Rails can't find gumby-framework gem assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, localhost, cloud9-ide, gumby-framework

I'm using a locally installed version of Cloud9 and Ruby on Rails. I've installed 'gumby-framework' and 'modernizr-rails' gems but when I add `//= require modernizr` to applications.js it can't find them.

When I run `$ bundle install` it lists both gems as installed. Here's what `$ gem env` comes back with:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
 - ruby
 - x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /usr/local/git/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
 - /Users/name/.rvm/bin
```

The file path of my project is 'Users/name/c9sdk/quote_app'.
I've just started working with Rails so I know I must be missing something obvious, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add them to `Gemfile`?

Comment: And restarted Rails server after that. Right?

Comment: Ugh I knew it was something obvious, that just did the trick. Thank you!